# In angular 1.5, is it possible to have nested child components like in React?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example, I made a slider component in React that takes child components to make a category slider.

So, it is something like:

```
<Slider>
  <Child someProps={this.props.someProps1} />
  <Child someProps={this.props.someProps2} />
  <Child someProps={this.props.someProps3} />
  <Child someProps={this.props.someProps4} />
</Slider>
```

Is something like this possible in angular 1.5?  I'm having a lot of trouble understanding angular components and it is not really ticking with me the way React does.

Thanks.

Comment: It's called transclusion in angular. Check out the "Intercomponent Communication" section of the component docs for an example https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication

Comment: Ah.  Thanks!  Angular seems a lot more complicated than React to pick up :(